# String with xaml or rtf to c# wpf richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, string, xaml, rtf

I got a string with xaml or rtf and want to know how to get it in a c# wpf richtextbox.

The two strings look like this and want to use one of them.

```
   string xaml = "<FlowDocument xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Paragraph>HOOFDDORP - Het zou helemaal niet noodzakelijk zijn voor <Run FontStyle="italic">SimCity </Run>om altijd met het internet verbonden te zijn, omdat er geen simulatie op de servers plaatsvindt. </Paragraph></FlowDocument>"

   string rtf = "{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\htmautsp\deff2{\fonttbl{\f0\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f2\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}\loch\hich\dbch\pard\plain\ltrpar\itap0{\lang1033\fs18\f2\cf0 \cf0\ql{\f2 {\ltrch HOOFDDORP - Het zou helemaal niet noodzakelijk zijn voor }{\i\ltrch SimCity }{\ltrch om altijd met het internet verbonden te zijn, omdat er geen simulatie op de servers plaatsvindt. }\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}}}"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import XAML into WPF RichTextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458141/import-xaml-into-wpf-richtextbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void populateRTF(string yourRTFString)
{
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(yourRTFString));
    yourRichTextBox.Selection.Load(memStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
}
```

Call using `populateRTF(rtf)`

Also, you'll need to escape your RTF string:

```
string rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\htmautsp\deff2{\fonttbl{\f0\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f2\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}\loch\hich\dbch\pard\plain\ltrpar\itap0{\lang1033\fs18\f2\cf0 \cf0\ql{\f2 {\ltrch HOOFDDORP - Het zou helemaal niet noodzakelijk zijn voor }{\i\ltrch SimCity }{\ltrch om altijd met het internet verbonden te zijn, omdat er geen simulatie op de servers plaatsvindt. }\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}}}"
```

Comment: My richtextbox doesn't have Selection.Load(); it is a richtextbox created in wpf

Comment: It should, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx

Comment: Ok finally fixed thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
  string content = "";
  textBox.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, content);
```